Как защитить flask-сайт от ботов-прослушивателей?
Можно ли как-то защитить сайт от ботов-прослушивателей, которые периодически стучаться на сайт: целенаправленно открывают главную страницу и уходят.
На саму работу сайта не влияет, но это не очень хорошо для поисковых систем, т.к. они думаю, что сайт не интересен и понижают его поисковую выдачу.
В какую сторону стоит посмотреть? Или единственный верный способ - это ставить проверку: "Докажите, что Вы не бот?"

Если они напрямую на сайт заходят (не из поиска) - это не влияет на поисковую выдачу. И даже если из поиска - поисковик ничего не знает о поведении посетителя на вашем сайте, он может разве что переходы из поиска посчитать.
